# Doctrine migrations custom flags

Tags: php, doctrine, migration

I am using a [doctrine/migrations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/2.1/reference/custom-integration.html#custom-integration) package in my project and wanted to do a custom migration command. I have managed to do so and have added it to a custom script:

```
$cli->addCommands(array(
    ...
    new CustomCommand()
));
```

This works fine and I have been able to override most of the things I was interested in changing (migration logic, template), however I am not sure exactly how can I add a flag where I can add multiple parameters.

My goal is ultimately doing something like:

```
php migration.php custom --table t1, t2, t3
```

I've seen that there is a method to add an 'option' like:

```
protected function configure(): void
{
    $this
        ->setName('...')
        ->setAliases(['custom'])
        ->setDescription('...')
        ->addOption(
            'editor-cmd',
            null,
            InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL,
            'Open file with this command upon creation.'
        );
    parent::configure();
}
```

I was trying to dig around the package source to figure it out, but I wasn't quite successful. I suppose in this specific case `'editor-cmd'` is a function/command which should be defined somewhere so it can be added to the scope like this, but I am not sure where is this happening.

Did someone do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It looks as if that is not a callback at all, but a simple shell parameter. So I've added this:

```
->addOption(
      'test',
      null,
      InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL,
      '...'
)
```

And then below in `execute()` method call it with:

```
$testCommand = $input->getOption('test');
```

So now I can call my script with:

```
php test-mig.php custom --test=my_test_var
```

and value of `$testCommand` will be `'my_test_var'`.